# retrieve random key element for std::map in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

how to get random key for std::map in c++ ? using iterator? 
I don't want extra data structure to be maintained

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`std::map` iterators are Bidirectional, which means selecting a random key will be `O(n)`. Without using another data structure, basically your only choice is to use `std::advance` with a random increment from `begin()`. For example:

```
std::map<K, V> m;
auto it = m.begin();
std::advance(it, rand() % m.size());
K random_key = it->first;
```

(Or swapping out `rand()` with (for example) `std::mt19939` if you have access to `<random>`).

Comment: Now there's `std::next`. :)

Comment: @erip, could you elaborate on `std::next`?  Why would it be better (or different) than `std::advance`?

Comment: @mannyglover It's been a few years, so things are a bit hazy. I think it was a tongue-in-cheek because the comment "your only choice is to use `std::advance`" is not technically true (but practically is the right choice).

Comment: Note that the complexity of `std::advance` (and `std::next`) is linear in general, but constant if the container has random access, e.g. `std::vector`. That's therefore a very nice fully generic way to get a random element from a container without affecting performances.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what's random for your purpose.  `std::map` is a sorted container, but doesn't support random access by element number.  Given that and knowledge of the set of keys, you can randomly select a point at which to dig into the map using `lower_bound` or `upper_bound` to find an element near there.  This has a tendency to keep picking elements based on the gap between them and other elements in the map, which means while the initial result may be considered effectively random if the elements/gaps are themselves effectively random, repeated selection of random elements will not be evenly distributed.

For example, say your keys were upper case letters, and the keys 'C', 'O', 'Q' and 'S' were in the map.  If you generate a random letter from A-Z, you'd be much more likely to end up on C, O or S than Q, as only PQR are near Q and using upper or lower bound you'd end up selecting two of those, so 2/26 chance despite there being only 4 elements.  Still, if there was some randomness to the selection of C, O, Q and S to begin with, you could argue that that the gaps and choice are random.

You could improve on that a little by stabbing into the container like this, then doing a small random number of iterator increments/decrements, but it still wouldn't be truly random.

A truly random result requires advancing a one-by-one traversal through the list, or the secondary indexing container you want to avoid.